How can I run If statements on every sheet that contains specific text using VBA?
I am trying to create a macro that will run If statements on every sheet with "(M)" at the end. I just need the macro to check cell "G8" in every worksheet with "(M)" at the end to see if there is a formula. If there is, then copy the formula over to "M8". If there isn't a formula then move on to the next sheet. Right now, the macro is doing nothing. I need it to work on all sheets with (M) at the end because this is a workbook where new sheets will be added and current sheets may be deleted, and I would like for the macro to work without having to change it when the sheets are changed.
Sub MondayCalc()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name Like "*(M)" Then
    
    If ws.Range("G8").HasFormula = True Then
        ws.Range("G8").Select
        ws.Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("G8:M8"), Type:=xlFillValues
        ws.Range("H8:M8").Select
        ws.Selection.Copy
        ws.Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    
ws.Range("A8").Select

End If

Next ws
End Sub

This is what my current code looks like. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Try If Trim(ws.Name) Like "*(M)" Then

All these selections are unnecessary. All you need is this:
Sub MondayCalc()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "*(M)" Then
            If ws.Range("G8").HasFormula Then
                ws.Range("G8:M8").FillRight
                ws.Range("H8:M8").Value = ws.Range("H8:M8").Value
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

